# PHP SVG Dynamically Create Colored US Map

Tags: php, css, svg, maps

I'm trying to create a US map with certain states colored certain colors for references.

Currently I have a code that will only color states one color. 
I need two colors so at the moment I am having to create two maps.

One of the codes for creating a single map with one color code is:

```
$bumperStates = array(
     "tn", // Tennessee
     "al", // Alabama
     "ga", // Georgia
     "ky", // Kentucky
     "ca", // California
     "nm", // New Mexico
     "wy", // Wyoming
     "ne", // Nebraska
     "ks", // Kansas
     "ok", // Oklahoma
     "tx", // Texas
     "ia", // Iowa
     "mo", // Montana
     "ar", // Arkansas
     "la", // Louisiana
     "ms", // Mississippi
     "fl", // Florida
     "nc", // North Carolina
     "va", // Virginia
     "wv", // West Virginia
     "oh", // Ohio
     "sd", // South Dakota
     "in", // Indiana
     "ky", // Kentucky
     "sc", // South Carolina
     "pa", // Pennsylvania
     "ny", // New York
     "vt", // Vermont
     "me", // Maine
     "il", // Illinois
     "de", // Delaware
     "nj", // New Jersey
     "nh", // New Hampshire
     "ri" // Rhode Island
);
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

function createPNG( $svgfile, $pngfile ) {
    $command = "rsvg " . $svgfile . " " . $pngfile;
    $make_map = system( $command, $retval );
    if ( $retval ) echo "PNG creation failed."; // Did it work?
}

$bumperstateArray = array();
// Add dot in front of each state to make it a CSS class selector
foreach ( $bumperStates as $bumperstate ) {
    $bumperstateArray[] = '.' . $bumperstate;
}
// Make array into a string consisting of a list of states
$bumperstateList = implode( ', ', $bumperstateArray );

// Generate new map data
$map = file_get_contents( "USA-map.svg" );
if ( $bumperStates ) {
    $newdata = preg_replace( '/\.bumperSign {/i', '.bumperSign, ' . $bumperstateList . ' {', $map );
}

// Write the new map to a file
/*
$fh = fopen( "newmap.svg", "w" );
fwrite( $fh, $newdata );
fclose( $fh );
*/

//createPNG( 'newmap.svg', 'newmap.png' );

// Output new SVG map
header( 'Content-type: image/svg+xml' );
print( $newdata );
flush();
```

And the other is:

```
$topstates = array(
     "wa", // Washington
     "ut", // Utag
     "co", // Colorado
     "mi", // Michigan
     "id", // Idaho
     "wy", // Wyoming
     "ct", // Connecticut
     "az", // Arizona
     "or", // Oregon
     "mt", // Montana
     "nv", // Nevada
     "nd", // North Dakota
     "mn", // Minnessota
     "wi", // Wisconsin
     "md", // Maryland
     "de", // Delaware
     "ma" // Massechusetts

);
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

function createPNG( $svgfile, $pngfile ) {
    $command = "rsvg " . $svgfile . " " . $pngfile;
    $make_map = system( $command, $retval );
    if ( $retval ) echo "PNG creation failed."; // Did it work?
}

$topstateArray = array();
// Add dot in front of each state to make it a CSS class selector
foreach ( $topstates as $topstate ) {
    $topstateArray[] = '.' . $topstate;
}
// Make array into a string consisting of a list of states
$topstateList = implode( ', ', $topstateArray );

// Generate new map data
$map = file_get_contents( "USA-map.svg" );
if ( $topstates ) {
    $newdata = preg_replace( '/\.topSign {/i', '.topSign, ' . $topstateList . ' {', $map );
}

// Write the new map to a file
/*
$fh = fopen( "newmap.svg", "w" );
fwrite( $fh, $newdata );
fclose( $fh );
*/

//createPNG( 'newmap.svg', 'newmap.png' );

// Output new SVG map
header( 'Content-type: image/svg+xml' );
print( $newdata );
flush();
```

And when I tried combining the two I came up with:

```
$bumperStates = array(
     "tn", // Tennessee
     "al", // Alabama
     "ga", // Georgia
     "ky", // Kentucky
     "ca", // California
     "nm", // New Mexico
     "wy", // Wyoming
     "ne", // Nebraska
     "ks", // Kansas
     "ok", // Oklahoma
     "tx", // Texas
     "ia", // Iowa
     "mo", // Montana
     "ar", // Arkansas
     "la", // Louisiana
     "ms", // Mississippi
     "fl", // Florida
     "nc", // North Carolina
     "va", // Virginia
     "wv", // West Virginia
     "oh", // Ohio
     "sd", // South Dakota
     "in", // Indiana
     "ky", // Kentucky
     "sc", // South Carolina
     "pa", // Pennsylvania
     "ny", // New York
     "vt", // Vermont
     "me", // Maine
     "il", // Illinois
     "de", // Delaware
     "nj", // New Jersey
     "nh", // New Hampshire
     "ri" // Rhode Island
);
$topStates = array(
     "wa", // Washington
     "ut", // Utag
     "co", // Colorado
     "mi", // Michigan
     "id", // Idaho
     "wy", // Wyoming
     "ct", // Connecticut
     "az", // Arizona
     "or", // Oregon
     "mt", // Montana
     "nv", // Nevada
     "nd", // North Dakota
     "mn", // Minnessota
     "wi", // Wisconsin
     "md", // Maryland
     "de", // Delaware
     "ma" // Massechusetts

);
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

function createPNG( $svgfile, $pngfile ) {
    $command = "rsvg " . $svgfile . " " . $pngfile;
    $make_map = system( $command, $retval );
    if ( $retval ) echo "PNG creation failed."; // Did it work?
}

$bumperstateArray = array();
// Add dot in front of each state to make it a CSS class selector
foreach ( $bumperStates as $bumperstate ) {
    $bumperstateArray[] = '.' . $bumperstate;
}
$topstateArray = array();
// Add dot in front of each state to make it a CSS class selector
foreach ( $topStates as $topstate ) {
    $topstateArray[] = '.' . $topstate;
}
// Make array into a string consisting of a list of states
$bumperstateList = implode( ', ', $bumperstateArray );
$topstateList = implode( ', ', $topstateArray );

// Generate new map data
$map = file_get_contents( "USA-map.svg" );
if ( $bumperStates ) {
    $newdata = preg_replace( '/\.bumperSign {/i', '.bumperSign, ' . $bumperstateList . ' {', $map );
}
if ( $topStates ) {
    $newdata .= preg_replace( '/\.topSign {/i', '.topSign, ' . $topstateList . ' {', $map );
}

// Write the new map to a file
/*
$fh = fopen( "newmap.svg", "w" );
fwrite( $fh, $newdata );
fclose( $fh );
*/

//createPNG( 'newmap.svg', 'newmap.png' );

// Output new SVG map
header( 'Content-type: image/svg+xml' );
print( $newdata );
flush();
```

Half of the map generates but then I get the following error:

`error on line 390 at column 12: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document`

The error has to be from the SVG file since it is the only one with over 300 lines.

I cannot post the contents of the SVG file because it is too long :/ StackOverflow says `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 113909`

All of the original files are located here: https://github.com/kaldari/SVG-map-maker

Maybe someone can tell me I did something wrong on the PHP side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The solution

You need to apply your second replace to the document that was already processed:

```
// Generate new map data (and assuming you want to keep $map intact)
$newdata = $map = file_get_contents( "USA-map.svg" );
if ( $bumperStates ) {
    $newdata = preg_replace( '/\.bumperSign {/i', '.bumperSign, ' . $bumperstateList . ' {', $newdata  );
}
if ( $topStates ) {
    $newdata = preg_replace( '/\.topSign {/i', '.topSign, ' . $topstateList . ' {', $newdata );
}
```

### The explanation

The error is pretty clear, you are trying to redeclare a xml document where one exists already. In details:

- A svg file is essentially a xml file
- You can't declare a xml document twice in the same file
- You are appending a svg file to another svg file which means you are declaring two xml documents in a single file

The issue is here:

```
if ( $topStates ) {
    $newdata .= preg_replace( '/\.topSign {/i', '.topSign, ' . $topstateList . ' {', $map );
}
```

Which basically results in this (and that's not allowed):

```
<?xml ...?><svg>...</svg><?xml ...?><svg>...</svg>
```

Comment: Works like a charm and up voted for the explanation :) I've never worked with svg before so that was all new to me. Thanks.

Also there is two errors in your answer, but easily solved. In the solution you left the `$` off of the `newdata` variables :) 

But once I added the `$` to each it works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Must have been a faulty copy/paste. Fixed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I've looked at the svg file and the states each have their names listed as an `id`. Could you think of any way to display the state names on the map?

Comment: You should probably make another question for that. I could have a look but i'm not that familiar with svg. And it would be more visible for people more qualified than me to answer.